# Records created via Slack Sales App into Salesforce

Tags: apex, trigger, integration, slack, slack-salesforce-app

I recently integrated slack with salesforce and tried creating records in salesforce via slack's Sales app shortcut "Create a Record".

The record is being created but I am unable to find any identifier which tells that this record is created through slack.

Is there any standard functionality or something through which we could identify such records except creating a custom field?

Additional Questions:

1. Is there some way to identify the slack channel details and member detail in Apex/Trigger when a record is created through Slack?
2. When using "Create a Record" shortcut, is there some way to pre-populate the form that pops up?
3. Create a Record has a three step process. Select Object -> Select RecordType -> Fill record details. Can we directly skip to Fill record details form somehow?

This is my first time integrating Slack with Salesforce and I went berserk searching for answers to these questions but no luck so far.

Any help will be much appreciated. :)

[image: Select Object]
[image: Select RT]
[image: Record Details Form]